# How to compile ros application manually by g++ and form object or library files

Tags: ros, compile, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been working on a project where I use ROS to create a c++ publisher and subscriber application. Publisher is running on my machine and the subscriber running on another remote machine connected through Wi-Fi. I use single master uri for both. Everything works fine.

Now I need to include my publisher program as library to another my c++ program, I know how to create headers and include them in another program for normal c++ applications.
But i don't know how to make a library file (as I understood it should compiled as static library) from my ros package.?

I am using ros indigo, Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201902/how-to-compile-ros-application-manually-by-g++-and-form-object-or-library-files/) by [m_ramshad](https://answers.ros.org/users/21095/m_ramshad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't have to compile it by hand. Catkin can compile libraries too.

The command you need is `add_library()`. Have a look at the [CMakeLists.txt documentation section 7.5](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt).

The library then gets put in den lib folder of your devel space.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m_ramshad](https://answers.ros.org/users/21095/m_ramshad/) on 2015-01-28**:
Thanks Benny, I was able to produce .so library file and i am now trying to include it in my program
I have a small clarification, do you think it is possible for me to compile and run my c++ program just by including the above mentioned .so file while that .so program have many dependencs in ros

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-28**:
If you use ROS functions in your library it will not work without the ROS dependencies.
You could use the recommended ROS design and put all your logic an a ROS-independent library and use this library in your ROS node.